# how can i use xml in c++?

Tags: c++, xml, opencv

i'm beginning in c++ and i try to use xml in my code, this is my source code :

```
    CvFileStorage * fileStorage;
    fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "facedata.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_WRITE );                            
    string d="apple";
    char* s=new char();
    strcpy(s,d.c_str());
    cvWrite(fileStorage, "word", s);
    cvReleaseFileStorage( &fileStorage );
    fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage( "facedata.xml", 0, CV_STORAGE_READ );
    s=cvReadStringByName(fileStorage, 0, "word",0);
    cout<<s<<endl;
```

but `s`does not return the content of `word`, i need your help.

Comment: Have you checked the actual contents of the file?

Comment: please use the c++ api, not the arcane c-one ! cv::FileStorage, etc.

Comment: You should take a look at tinyxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

again, please use opencv's c++ api:

```
cv::FileStorage fs("facedata.xml", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "word" << "apple";
fs.release();

cv::FileStorage fs2("facedata.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
string s;
fs2["word"] >> s;
fs2.release();
```

Comment: Is the asymmetry avoidable ? I would like `fs["word"] << "apple";`

Comment: i would like that, too, but no.

Comment: thank you very much and i would like if you can give me some links for learning more  about xml  in c++

Comment: @David, opencv's FileStorage *uses* xml (or yml) for storage, but is basically a key-value store. you cannot read arbitrary xml with that (use tinyxml or the like for that)